# SQL remove month and day but not year, regex?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, regex

Not sure if I should use a regex, and if so which, but I'm using SQL (Sequel Pro)

For a particular instance in a table (about 200 columns) I want to remove everything that precedes the year (such as for 3/13/2012 I want to remove 3/13/ ). Some entries only have a year, and some have the month and day preceding the year.

How can I remove the month and day without removing the year in SQL?

Comment: Provide a schema of your table(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,{Your Column Name Here}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this in MYSQL

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(datecolumn, "%m/%d/%Y")) from table
```

and in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT YEAR(datecolumn) AS Date
FROM table
```

Comment: if i want to update the date (year, in this case) column to remove the day and month, would this work?

UPDATE Table1
SET YEAR(year) AS year
WHERE id = 68